# How to DM all users in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I don't know how can I setup a command to DM all users in a server.
I already tried to use this:

```
@commands.command(aliases=["senddm", "alldm"])
async def all_dm(self, ctx, message):
    await ctx.send(f"DM everyone with `{message}` in `{ctx.guild.name}`? [y/n]")

    def check_data(message):
        return message.author == ctx.message.author

    while True:
        try:
            msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check_data, timeout=int(timeout))
            if msg.content == "y":
                await ctx.send(waitmsg)
                for user in list(ctx.guild.members):
                    try:
                        await user.send(nick=message)
                    except Exception:
                        pass
                await ctx.send(donemsg)
                return
            if msg.content == "n":
                await ctx.send(no_msg)
                return
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await ctx.send(timeout_msg)
            return
```

I need another code to setup the command

Comment: I believe that is against Discord's spam ToS. You should probably just ping everybody. You don't want your bot to get rate limited.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to do that, creating private channels is subject to strict rate limits, and your bot can be quarantined very quickly. You can find other ways to contact users of a server like mentions.

Here's the doc's article on ratelimits: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#rate-limits